# Textbox value to database using stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I m learning business logic and data logic and program readability.

I have 1 DL(data logic) class with all the stored procedures, then I have a BL(business logic) that connects DL and BL.
Then I have a form class, where I can add new users to the database. 
How can I connect form, BL and DL?
DL class stored procedure:

```
public DataSet InsertClubRoles(int RoleID, string Roledesc, string Createdby)
        {
            DataSet mydataset = new DataSet();
            SqlCommand cmdclubroles = new SqlCommand();
            //get stored procedure
            cmdclubroles.CommandText = "usp_insertrlubroles";
            cmdclubroles.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;     
            //connect
            cmdclubroles.Connection = jadcoreConnection.GetConnection();
            //parameters
            cmdclubroles.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoleID", Convert.ToInt32(RoleID));
            cmdclubroles.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Roledesc", Roledesc);
            cmdclubroles.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Createdby", Createdby);

            SqlDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdclubroles);
            mySqlDataAdapter.Update(mydataset); 

            return mydataset;
        }
```

Heres the business logic:

```
public DataSet insertingclubroles(int RoleID, string Roledesc, string Createdby)
{
    DataSet ids = new DataSet();

    ids = new GetClubRoles().InsertClubRoles(RoleID, Roledesc, Createdby);

    return ids;

}
```

Lastly here's the submit button and save role method in a different form:

```
private void Savebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        saverole();
        MessageBox.Show("Club role saved successfuly");                     
    }
    catch (Exception er)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(er.Message.ToString());
    }
}

public void saverole()
{
    ClubRoles cr = new ClubRoles();
    cr.insertingclubroles(2,"as","me");

    //need text for description
    //need select which client is selected
}
```

How can I connect all three? I know the textbox values need to be assigned to the stored procedures parameter but how?

Thanks in advance, sorry if this is too long, trying to explain it as best as I can.

Comment: In your DL layer, you will want separate methods to insert and to retrieve data. The only thing that your insert methods should possibly return is that amount of records inserted and/or any errors experienced. Once you make that separation, the connection between the layers will be simple.

Comment: I will just leave this here. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: @JRLambert I indeed have separated insert methods and retrieve data

Comment: @Noonmoon You may have partially but you have an insert method returning a `DataSet`.

Comment: @JRLambert I removed the dataset as marc_s showed, now I am trying to figure out how I will send Textbox value into the database from the form class.

Comment: @Noonmoon Ok, well how would you access the Textbox's value if you were not sending it to a database? You would use the `TextBox.Text` property, right? Can you get it from there?

Comment: @JRLambert Yes I will use the Textbox.text, but would I pass it as a parameter of 'public DataSet InsertClubRoles(int RoleID, string Roledesc, string Createdby)'?

Comment: @Noonmoon Yes, that is how you would do it in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To acutally **INSERT** data, you should be using the `.ExecuteNonQuery` method on `SqlCommand` - something like this:

```
public void InsertClubRoles(int RoleID, string Roledesc, string Createdby)
{
    using (SqlCommand cmdclubroles = new SqlCommand()) 
    {
        // get stored procedure
        cmdclubroles.CommandText = "usp_insertrlubroles";
        cmdclubroles.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;     

        // connection
        cmdclubroles.Connection = jadcoreConnection.GetConnection();

        // parameters
        cmdclubroles.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoleID", Convert.ToInt32(RoleID));
        cmdclubroles.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Roledesc", Roledesc);
        cmdclubroles.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Createdby", Createdby);

        // execute the INSERT statement
        cmdclubroles.Connection.Open();
        cmdclubroles.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmdclubroles.Connection.Close();
    }
}
```

**Update:** to pass in the values from your textboxes into the `SaveRole` method - add some parameters to it!

```
public void SaveRole(int RoleID, string RoleDesc, string CreatedBy)
{
    ClubRoles cr = new ClubRoles();
    cr.insertingclubroles(RoleID, RoleDesc, CreatedBy);

    //need text for description
    //need select which client is selected
}
```

and then from your form's save method, set those parameters:

```
private void Savebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SaveRole(Convert.ToInt32(tbxRoleID.Text), tbxRoleDesc.Text, tbxCreatedBy.Text);
        MessageBox.Show("Club role saved successfully");
    }
    catch (Exception er)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(er.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure how my Business logic will look like now since were using sqlcommand

Comment: @Noonmoon: not sure what you mean - this ***IS*** using `SqlCommand`, too !

Comment: I updated my Data Logic like you said, now I am trying to figure out how I will send Textbox value into the database from the form class...